# Ember FixtureAdapter error: cannot assign new id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my ember integration tests I'm getting this error:

Assertion failed: An adapter cannot assign a new id to a record that already has an id.  had id: fixture-0 and you tried to update it with null. This likely happened because your server returned data in response to a find or update that had a different id than the one you sent.

Answer (score 0):

I had set the ApplicationSerializer up to map the primaryKey to "_id" as follows:

```
Encompass.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: "_id"
});
```

The fixture data was using "id" so when it went to save it, it didn't see an "_id" come back it coerced the undefined id, to null and tried to update that.

Wrapping that ApplicationSerializer assignment in an

```
if(window.TESTING)
```

resolved it for me

Comment: Just to comment, you can change `primaryKeys` for multiple models like   `App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSeralizer.extend(...)`